# How to mock a module with typescript namespace?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

This is the function under test:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

function signInWithGoogle() {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}
```

firebase has below type definition:

```
declare namespace firebase.auth
```

and

```
function auth(app?: firebase.app.App): firebase.auth.Auth;
```

```js
jest.mock('firebase', () => {
  // Don't know how to mock, what should be returned?  
})
```

I need mock `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()`, `firebase.auth()` and `signInWithRedirect` methods of firebase.

But the `firebase.auth` can be an object or a function. What should be returned in the `factory` of `jest.mock`?

Does jestjs support this kind of mock or spy? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript functions are objects of type Function. And to every object you can assign properties so you can mock it as:

```
jest.mock('firebase', () => {
  const auth = jest.fn();
  auth.GoogleAuthProvider = jest.fn();
  auth.Auth = jest.fn();
  return { auth };
});
```

or you can use Jest's auto-mocking without factory function:

```
jest.mock('firebase');
```

and then mock the implementation

```
// based on your question (not tested)
firebase.auth.mockImplementation(() => new firebase.auth.Auth())
```

Comment: It's very helpful! After reading your answer, I'm aware of that. You reminded me! Thanks dude! I finished my example and post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

From @Teneff's answer, I figure it out. The point is like @Teneff said, typescript namespace is some kind of a JS function after compiling and type erasure. After knowing this, of course, you can assign properties to JS function. Here is the completed working code example:

`index.ts`:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';

export function signInWithgoogle() {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}
```

For simple, I add `@ts-ignore` comment in order to ignore the type check.

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { signInWithgoogle } from './';
import firebase from 'firebase';

jest.mock('firebase', () => {
  const auth = jest.fn();
  const mAuth = { signInWithRedirect: jest.fn() };
  // @ts-ignore
  auth.GoogleAuthProvider = jest.fn();
  // @ts-ignore
  auth.Auth = jest.fn(() => mAuth);
  return { auth };
});

describe('signInWithgoogle', () => {
  it('should mock firebase with typescript namespace', () => {
    // @ts-ignore
    firebase.auth.mockImplementation(() => new firebase.auth.Auth());
    signInWithgoogle();
    expect(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(firebase.auth).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/mock-ts-namespace/index.spec.ts
  signInWithgoogle
    ✓ should mock firebase with typescript namespace (7ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.964s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/mock-ts-namespace